# Oracle PL/SQL query regarding handling data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a live production table which has more than 1 million records. Now i don't need to tamper anything on this table and would like to create another table which fetches all records from this live production table. I would schedule a job which can take entries from my main table and inserts them to my new table. But i don't want all the records daily; i just need the records added on a daily basis in the production table to get added in my new table.
Please suggest a faster and efficient approach.

Comment: Why do you *want* to do this?  And are you really using both MySQL and Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger to send the INSERTED/UPDATED/DELETED row to the new table, however this feels like reinventing the wheel on the most basic level.

You could just use asynchronous replication rather than hand-rolling it all yourself, this is probably safer, more sustainable and scalable. You could add as many tables as you like to the replicated source.

Answer (score 1):

Copying one million records from an existing table to a new table should not take very long -- and might even be faster than figuring out what records to copy.  You could do something like:

```
truncate table copytable;

insert into copytable
     select *
     from productiontable;
```

Note that you should explicitly list the columns when doing the `insert`.

You can also readily add new records -- assuming you have some form of `id` on the production table, such as an `id` assigned by a sequence.  Then you can do:

```
insert into copytable
    select *
    from productiontable p
    where p.id > (select max(id) from copytable);
```